# Error en Test : relación no existe en test. Ayuda

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo una ayuda que pedirles:

Resulta que estoy realizando unos test a una views de un sitio web que devuelve un json pero se arroja el siguiente error

```
  File "C:\Users\note\Envs\gadash\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.
, line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "listado_inicial" does not exist
```

el test es el siguiente:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client
from .models import *

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def SetUp(self):
        self.cliente=Client()
    def test_details(self):
        rp=c.get('/intra/datos-grafico/', data={'cod_suc':309},content_type='application/json')
    self.assertEqual(len(rp.json()['rows']),0)
```

la view es:

```
def datos(request,cod_suc):

if cod_suc==0:
    edad_stock=v.objects.raw('''select 1 as id_number, sum("SALDO") as s ,l."EDICION" as edi from ventas v join **listado_inicial** l on l."ISBN"=v."ISBN" where v."FECHA"=(select max(v."FECHA") from ventas v) group by l."EDICION" ''')
else:
    edad_stock=v.objects.raw('''select 1 as id_number, sum("SALDO") as s ,l."EDICION" as edi from ventas v join **listado_inicial** l on l."ISBN"=v."ISBN" where v."FECHA"=(select max(v."FECHA") from ventas v) and "COD_SUCURSAL"=%s group by l."EDICION" ''',[cod_suc])

datos_aux={}
datos=[]

for e in edad_stock:       
    datos_aux["saldo"]=int(e.s)
    datos_aux["edicion"]=e.edi
    datos.append(datos_aux)
    datos_aux={}



description2={"saldo":("number","saldo"),"edicion":("string","edicion")}
data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(description2)
data_table.LoadData(datos)
j=data_table.ToJSon(columns_order=("edicion", "saldo"))


return HttpResponse(j, content_type='application/json')
```

¿Alguien ha padecido lo mismo?, ¿me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Hola, en tu test estás usando `SetUp`, el nombre correcto del método es `setUp`. Dentro de tu prueba estás usando `c.get()`, ¿no sería `self.client.get()`?

Comment: Aunque lo copié del sitio de django, tus correcciones son correctas pero el problema persiste. Por lo que he leído, tiene que ver con las migraciones a la base de datos temporal para hacer los test pero no sé puntualmente qué hacer para resolverlo. Gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Según la documentación todas las migraciones son aplicadas al ejecutar las pruebas. Tal vez puedas incluir mayor información para poder ayudarte: el error completo, el código real (el ejemplo que has puesto no debería funcionar por lo que menciono en mi primer comentario), cómo ejecutas las pruebas, tus modelos, etc.

Comment: Sería bueno que agregaras también la versión exacta de django con la cual estás trabajando

Comment: Hola cesar. estoy trabajando con la ultima de django, la actualicé hace días atras. Creo que es la 2.0